# Cannot have two routes at once

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create eshop (i want to learn laravel) with some form to add data.

I have two routes, first for display product(product/{id}) and second to create new product(product/create).
But when i try to display some product, it shows 404, same as on second site.

When i delete second route, everything works, but together they don't work.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    // Products
    Route::get('/product/', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.all'); //All products
    Route::get('/product/{id}/', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.id'); // Only one product with id

    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

        // Products
        Route::get('/product/create/', 'ProductController@create');// Form to add new product


    });

});
```

When i go to url /product/8 i want to show product with id 8, but on url /product/create i want to show form to create new product

Comment: you may want to add the create route first.

Comment: Now the create route works, but the second don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your second route meaning `/product/create` overrides the first one, so you either move the `/product/{id}` route below the create route, or you can always add `regex` constraint on the route like this:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}/', 'ProductController@show')
   ->name('product.id')
   ->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to add the web middleware since, it's added to all routes in `web.php`

```
    // Products
    Route::get('/product/', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.all'); //All products


    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

        // Products
        Route::get('/product/create/', 'ProductController@create');// Form to add new product


    });

    Route::get('/product/{id}/', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.id'); // Only one product with id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your create route at the top because your route `/product/create` overrides the `/product/{id}`

Change your routes just like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    // Products
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        // Products
        Route::get('/product/create/', 'ProductController@create');// Form to add new product
    });

    Route::get('/product/', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.all'); //All products
    Route::get('/product/{id}/', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.id'); // Only one product with id

});
```

Comment: Now the create route works, but the second with id don't.

Comment: wait, just now I have noticed, why don't you use post method for create route since it's form submission?